# More elegant inner methods declarations (without all the clutter)?

Tags: java, syntax, inner-classes

I have a recursive method that computes x^n with a certain algorithm, but this is of no importance here. What matters is my helper function which keeps track of recursive calls of this algorithm.

```
public class FastPot {

    public static double fastPotRek(double x, int n) {
        class Aux {
            private double aux(double x, int n, int c) {
                if (n == 0) {System.out.print("It took "+c+" recursive calls to compute "); return 1;}
                else return (n % 2 == 0) ? aux(x*x, n/2, c+1)
                        : x * aux(x, n-1, c+1);
            }
        }
        Aux a = new Aux();
        return a.aux(x, n, 0);
    }
}
```

To organize that somewhat I wanted to declare `aux` inside `fastPotRek`, and for that you have to use an inner class, whose methods I can't declare static. Because of this I instantiate `Aux a = new Aux();` to be able to call `aux`.

Please tell me there is a way to make this more elegant and show me what I have overlooked... Like beeing able to make `aux` static somehow or not needing to instantiate `Aux`.

Comment: you could make `Aux` a static inner class of `FastPot` or use lambdas. Besides that why don't you just use a normal static method? If you try to organize code but generate clutter that way I'm not sure this way of organizing things makes much sense.

Comment: I don't really see the point of an inner class here. Moving your `aux` method at the same level as `fastPotRek` as a `private static` method will do the job.

Comment: I'm aware this looks terrible, this is why I asked if you can nest in this case without it becomming a mess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post this answer although many people (including me) will not be happy with this. Please **don't use this kind of code**:

```
public static double fastPotRek(double x, int n) {
    return new Cloneable() {
        private double aux(double x, int n, int c) {
            if (n == 0) {System.out.print("It took "+c+" recursive calls to compute "); return 1;}
            else return (n % 2 == 0) ? aux(x*x, n/2, c+1) : x * aux(x, n-1, c+1);
        }
    }.aux(x, n, 0);
}
```

Again, i **highly suggest** to use a private static method like:

```
public static double fastPotRek(double x, int n) {
    return aux(x,n,0);
}
private static double aux(double x, int n, int c) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for inner class and no need to make that static as well:

```
public class FastPot {
    //Static, use only from within FastPot
      private static double aux(double x, int n, int c) {
                if (n == 0) {
                  System.out.print("It took "+c+" recursive calls to compute "); 
                  return 1;
                } else {
                  return (n % 2 == 0) ? aux(x*x, n/2, c+1)
                        : x * aux(x, n-1, c+1);
                }
            }
    }

    //Your outward interface
    public static double fastPotRek(double x, int n) {
        return aux(x, n, 0);
    }
}
```

Or if you insist on using an inner class:

```
public class FastPot {
    //Static, use only from within FastPot
    private static class Aux {
      private static double aux(double x, int n, int c) {
                if (n == 0) {
                  System.out.print("It took "+c+" recursive calls to compute "); 
                  return 1;
                } else {
                  return (n % 2 == 0) ? aux(x*x, n/2, c+1)
                        : x * aux(x, n-1, c+1);
                }
            }
    }


    //Your outward interface
    public static double fastPotRek(double x, int n) {
        return Aux.aux(x, n, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
Aux a = new Aux();
return a.aux(x, n, 0);
```

I would write it like this (Does the same):

```
return new Aux().aux(x, n, 0);
```

**Edit:** I´m done with StackOverflow. You guys don´t want help? I won´t give it. From now on, I will only ask about **MY** problems, and won´t answer.

Comment: this is not really answering the question ;) this should be a comment not an answer!

Comment: "Please tell me there is a way to make this more elegant and show me what I have overlooked... Like beeing able to make aux static somehow or not needing to instantiate Aux."   My code does not instantiate Aux :)

Comment: @Mayuso yes it does! There is the `new` keyword